# converting hex integer to Color in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

What is the difference between:

```
private Color GetColorFromInteger(int color)
        {
            return Color.Rgb(Color.GetRedComponent(color), Color.GetGreenComponent(color), Color.GetBlueComponent(color));         
        }
```

and:

```
private Color GetColorFromInteger(int color)
        {         
            return new Color(color);
        }
```

?

The first works perfectly but when I replace it with the second my program works differently. I do not know what's the problem. I think both are the same.

Comment: Could you be more specific on "works differently"? Does a different color appear? (I suspect that the alpha channel is being lost.)

Comment: @JoeSewell it's hard to explain. the app graphic changes. Some bars disappear. So something is different in this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in your examples is whether the alpha (transparency) value of `color` is obeyed.

Per [the Android documentation on android.graphics.Color](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#color-ints), an integer color value consists of a byte each for alpha, red, green, and blue components, i.e.: `0xAARRGGBB` (written out in big endian notation). The red `RR`, green `GG`, and blue `BB` components are somewhat easy to understand - the value of each component corresponds to the intensity of that primary color.

The [alpha component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) `AA` is essentially the *transparency* of that pixel when the image in question is placed on top of another image. If pixel `x` of image `X` overlays pixel `y` of image `Y`, then `x`'s alpha component determines how much of the final rendered pixel `z` comes from `x` and how much from `y`. If the alpha value is high, more of `z`'s color will come from `x`; if the alpha value is low, more of `z`'s color will come from `y`. The highest value `0xFF` indicates `x` is completely opaque - `z` and `x` will be the same color, regardless of `y`. The lowest value `0x00` indicates `x` is completely transparent  - `z` and `y` will be the same color, regardless of `x`.

In the first example, you extract the red, green, and blue components from the integer with e.g. [`GetRedComponent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.graphics.color.getredcomponent?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9). Notice that you don't extract the alpha value. Then, you call [`Rgb`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.graphics.color.rgb?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9), which [is documented in the Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#rgb(int,%20int,%20int)) as always setting the alpha component to `0xFF` - completely opaque. So, no matter what value the `color` parameter is, it will never have any transparency.

In the second example, you provide `color` directly to [the constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.graphics.color.-ctor?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9#Android_Graphics_Color__ctor_System_Int32_), which appears to take alpha channel into account.

So it seems you're input `color` has an alpha value of something other than `0xFF`. In your comments on the question, you say some bars "disappear" - it's likely that your bars are technically there, they're just colored with `0x00` for full transparency and thus can't be seen.

Comment: Yes. Setting the alpha = 0xff fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try ctrl + click over the "Color" to see all the methods inside it (if you are using [VisualStudio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/)).

There are two differents Color classes:

**Xamarin.Forms.Color and Android.Graphics.Color**

make sure of which namespace you are using, that can be the reason why they work differently.

I recommend the using of hex code instead of int, there are some sites that you can [convert int rgb to hex code](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hex.html), I just think that it is easier to use.

Inside the Color:

[image]

Comment: It's Android.Graphics.Color in both methods.

Comment: if you open the class (ctrl + click) you will find out: public Color(int argb) and public Color(int r, int g, int b). You are using two different functions of the same class, you should use an argb int instead of rgb

Comment: I just added a print of what I can see inside the class you are using, I hope that can help you. Notice that you have differents parameters to the same call, but no one of them is a int rgb

Comment: Thank you but no images are visible. bte, my problem was solved.